# what are the jars needed to set on classpath during storm hbase integration

Tags: maven, jar, classpath, hbase, apache-storm

i am trying to integrate storm and hbase ,and my program is getting submitted to storm topology without any error or exception but when i check the logs i am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.storm.hbase.bolt.HBaseBolt  and i have already added storm-hbase-0.9.3.jar to classpath i.e storm lib folder still getting the exception at run time -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.storm.hbase.bolt.HBaseBolt     at
>   backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultSerializationDelegate.deserialize(DefaultSerializationDelegate.java:58)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:89)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.utils.Utils.getSetComponentObject(Utils.java:228)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.task$get_task_object.invoke(task.clj:73)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data$fn__3131.invoke(task.clj:180)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.util$assoc_apply_self.invoke(util.clj:850)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data.invoke(task.clj:173)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.task$mk_task.invoke(task.clj:184)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor$fn__3310.invoke(executor.clj:323)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   clojure.core$map$fn__4207.invoke(core.clj:2485)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at
>   clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invoke(protocols.clj:30)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at
>   clojure.core.protocols$fn__6026.invoke(protocols.clj:54)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at
>   clojure.core.protocols$fn__5979$G__5974__5992.invoke(protocols.clj:13)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6177)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at clojure.core$into.invoke(core.clj:6229)
>   ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor.invoke(executor.clj:323)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__3743$exec_fn__1108__auto____3744$iter__3749__3753$fn__3754.invoke(worker.clj:382)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]    at
>   clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]     at
>   clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]  at
>   clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]     at
>   clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:2780) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]  at
>   clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:2796) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]  at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__3743$exec_fn__1108__auto____3744.invoke(worker.clj:382)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
>     at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]    at
>   clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]   at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__3743$mk_worker__3799.doInvoke(worker.clj:354)
>   [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]    at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:461)
>   [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]  at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
>     at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]    at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source)
>   [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3] Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.storm.hbase.bolt.HBaseBolt     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_72]   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:625)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]    at
>   backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultSerializationDelegate.deserialize(DefaultSerializationDelegate.java:52)
>   ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]     ... 36 common frames omitted
>   2015-04-01T18:20:13.559+0530 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error
>   on initialization") java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error on
>   initialization")  at
>   backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:325)
>   [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]    at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__3743$mk_worker__3799.doInvoke(worker.clj:354)
>   [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]  at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]    at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:461)
>   [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]  at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
>     at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]    at
>   backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source)
>   [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]

can anyone tell me how to resolve this ,m i missing any jar at classpath?

Comment: add this in your pom   <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
<artifactId>storm-hbase</artifactId>
<version>0.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: it was giving error in pom 
Missing artifact com.github.ptgoetz:storm-hbase:jar:0.1.3-SNAPSHOT

Comment: and  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
   <artifactId>storm-hbase</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.2</version>
  </dependency> is already added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last added all the jars of the pom.xml in lib folder by using the plugin -

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>/usr/local/storm/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
```

and everything worked fine .